# How to insert time into MySQL database?

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I want to insert time into database.
Ive viewed various codes but all of them involve DateTime class. Here I just want to insert Time and not the date but I keep getting this error.

> Incorrect time value: '' for column 'time' at row 1

Heres my c# code:

```
    public partial class Calendar : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        String connection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebappconString"].ToString();

        protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);

            DateTime time= new DateTime() ;
            String t = time.ToShortDateString();
            String query = @"Insert into Event (Proposedby, Date, Time, Society) 
values(@TextBox1,@TextBox4 ,@TextBox5,@TextBox6)";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextBox1", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextBox4", Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextBox5", TextBox5.Text.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TextBox6", TextBox6.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the content of TextBox5.Text that you use to set the value for the relevant parameter? And also what is the datatype of the datatable column Time?

Comment: In database column type is Time and i tried two values 1- TextBox5.Text=12:00 and one time it wasn't given any value

Comment: You need to cast your TextBox5 to the proper object type.

Comment: You should reconsider your variable naming...!

Comment: Fixed. terrible naming...

Comment: Cannot reproduce at all. Also with NOT NULL or passing an empty string, a Time column is set to its default of 00:00:00. Only with a clearly incorrect value like "ab:cc" I get the mentioned error but with a different text

Comment: I just entered 12:00:00 and still an error @Steve

Comment: What is the version of your MySql.Data.dll and what version of the framework are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is stating that Time which is textbox5.text is empty. You cannot insert a empty string into the database table time column.

You will need to add a guard for that case.

Comment: But when I give it a some value, it still gave the same error

Comment: What value did you give it?

Comment: @puffles Also what is the mysql column type of Time

Comment: it is Time and I gave 12:00 and 12:00:00

Comment: @puffles http://forums.asp.net/t/1214821.aspx?How+to+insert+Time+to+MySql check this link.